# OpenAPI generator: select or skip APIs by tags

Tags: openapi, code-generation, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have a big OpenAPI file with lots of methods tagged with a list of APIs, for example:

```
tags:
  - name: Marketplace API
    description: APIs used in order to use Marketplace Payment Flow
  - name: Payment API
    description: Payment API V4. If your integration is using API V2, <a href="/docs/api-migration/payments/">go to migration guide</a>.
  - name: Payouts API
    description: This API allows a merchant to make transfers using a card or a token. He can also retrieve info about past payouts or the current payout balance.
```

is there any generator parameters or other way for skipping APIs I don't need to be generated?

My current generation command:

```
for generator in $(cat generator-list.txt)
do
    npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
        --input-spec https://***/docs/swagger/api/v4/docs.yml \
        --generator-name ${generator} \
        --output ./client_${generator} \
        --verbose
done
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to setup your [`.openapi-generator-ignore`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#ignore-file-format)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `--global-property` to define which APIs, models or supportingFiles you want

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i specfile.yml -g go \ 
    --global-property apis="tag1:tag2:tag3"
```

See OpenAPI Generator [customization page](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#selective-generation)

Comment: any idea how to pass globalProperties in the `openapitools.json`?

Comment: this is not what the customization page says and it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably to use the `.openapi-generator-ignore`:
Suppose you only want the model. Then the content must be:

```
# Don't generate api code
api/*
# Don't generate supporting code
*.ts
*.json
*.sh
*.md
```

I used this, and low and behold, it works.